# Build pipeline for Xamarin.Android project targeting API 28

Tags: xamarin.android, azure-devops

I'm trying to build a Xamarin.Android project targeting Android P (API 28) using Azure DevOps/VSTS. The build is failing because it doesn't have API 28 added to the Android SDK on the build server. How would I go about setting that up on the build server? On my local instance I would setup the Android SDK using Tools -> Open Android SDK Manager, but that process requires using the GUI which I don't have on the build server.

The exact build error is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(627,2): Error XA5207: Could not find android.jar for API Level 28. This means the Android SDK platform for API Level 28 is not installed. Either install it in the Android SDK Manager (Tools > Open Android SDK Manager...), or change your Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is installed. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar missing.)

Comment: If you have access to a command line and can navigate to the SDK path, you can download the `android-28` platform via [`sdkmanager`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the Azure Pipelines hosted build agent? It should [already have API 28 installed](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/93f42c59deef67e4e218d6a6e31047e91c7f65cd/images/linux/scripts/installers/android.sh#L26). If that's not working, please file an issue in that repo.

On a private agent, you can use Android's [sdkmanager](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/93f42c59deef67e4e218d6a6e31047e91c7f65cd/images/linux/scripts/installers/android.sh#L26) to install API 28.

Comment: I'm new to this product. The build pipeline says Pool: Hosted VS2017 and Agent:Hosted Agent. When I click "Information" for Hosted VS2017 it lists API 27 as the latest, and I noticed Visual Studio is at version 15.8.1. Is there any way to get a newer agent?

Comment: Oh, we may have just added that API version then. The agents update automatically. Expect that in the next 1-2 weeks. And sorry for the "inside baseball" references - I've been knee deep in the product for a while and wasn't considering an outside perspective. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Hi, I've been waiting a few weeks and the build agent is still listing Visual Studio 2017 15.8.1. We're now on 15.8.6 locally. Do you have any idea what to do here? I can click "Update All Agents" under the "Default" agent but there is no feedback whatsoever after clicking that. I wait a few minutes, and check the details for the VS2017 Agent and it still lists 15.8.1. The "..." menu next to VS2017 Agent doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: Updating agents won't work with the hosted pool. A new Windows image should be hitting your account in the next 48 hours

Comment: @MattCooper hey Matt sorry for highjacking an old SO question but I think I have the opposite problem, I had a build that was working fine some weeks ago, and suddenly fails with `Error XA5207: Could not find android.jar for API Level 15` without having made any changes/commits to the repo. I don't find any references to "15" in the project folder so I'm out of ideas of how to fix this CI build

Comment: Hey @knocte please file an issue here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I found success using windows-2019 Ensure you are using NuGet 5.8 (I know frustrating this isn't the error)