# AzureDevOps net6.0-android Failing with XA5207: Could not find android.jar for API level 31

Tags: azure-devops, .net-6.0, net6.0-android

I'm trying to build a new net6.0-android in AzureDevOps and am seeing the following error.

```
##[error]/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Darwin/32.0.509/tools/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(533,2): Error XA5207: Could not find android.jar for API level 31. This means the Android SDK platform for API level 31 is not installed. Either install it in the Android SDK Manager (Tools > Open Android SDK Manager...), or change the Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is installed. (/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-31/android.jar missing.)
```

At first this was happening intermittently but now it seems to be happening on every build.

I don't really understand the error as Android 31 tooling is installed on the macOS-13 agents that I am using. There are several posts of people getting the same problem locally where its suggested its an issue with the Visual Studio installation and therefore fixing the installation is the answer, however its not clear why this would happen in AzureDevOps and how the installation would be fixed as part of a pipeline.

Comment: There is no Xamarin bundle symlinks in macos-13 image now([macOS 13 (20231025) Image Update](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/releases/tag/macos-13%2F20231025.2)), did you try to use macos-12? Or you can use self-hosted agent which mentioned in similar [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52298490/14996050).

Comment: We are building a net6.0-android app using dotnet build, I can only assume this is still using Xamarin.Android under the hood.

Comment: i notice your another [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77429820/azuredevops-install-android-version-from-pipeline) was answered with `SDKmanager tool` install on agent, you can give a try.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this problem, its because Android API 31 has been removed from the macOS-13 agents.

I've found that my issues is fixed by going to net7.0-android but the other thing I was going to try was to install Android 31 as part of the pipeline as described here: [AzureDevOps Install Android Version from Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77429820/azuredevops-install-android-version-from-pipeline)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. In order to let others who have the similar question with you know how you resolved it more clearly, it's suggested that you [accept your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) according to How does accepting an answer work. Thanks!