# AzureDevOps Install Android Version from Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, .net-6.0, net6.0-android

We are building a net6.0-android app using AzureDevOps, we need to use an Android API level that is not installed on the macos-13 agent by default.

Is there a way for us to install the particular android version we need via the pipeline?

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Comment: I think the answer below on how to use brew to install the Android tooling gives us what we need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way for us to install the particular android version we need via the pipeline?

Based on your requirement, you can use the [SDKmanager tool](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdkmanager)  to install the particular android version.

Here is an example:

Bash Script:

```
steps:
- bash: |
   brew install --cask android-commandlinetools
   
   brew install --cask xamarin-android
   
   
   echo y | sdkmanager 'build-tools;31.0.0' --sdk_root=/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk
   
   echo y | sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-31" --sdk_root=/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk
   
   
   ...
```

**Note:** When you use MacOS-13 in Azure DevOps Pipeline, you need to install the Android SDK in the path:**/Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk**

Answer (score 0):

Add a **Command line task** in Azure DevOps and then add the following script in it:

**"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat" "platforms;android-28"**

This will install the specific Android version that you mention as platforms argument in above command.